# Curve only extrudes on z axis

Tags: bezier-curves

I tried to converte a part of a circle (I deleted the other verticies) into a curve and extrude it, but it only extruded on z axis, but I actually want to have like a pipe.

Does anyone have an idea what to do?
Thank you :)

[image: Problem shown here]

Comment: Under Bevel > Depth, increase the value?

Answer (score 0):

Right click your mesh and choose *Convert To > Curve* then under *Object Data Properties > Bevel > Depth* increase this *Depth* field.

[image]